# ocaml - iterate values two by two in a list

Tags: ocaml

Is there a way to iterate over a list in two values? Something like:

```
let my_list : int list = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7];;

let iterate_by_two elem1 elem2 = 
    if elem1 < elem2 then Printf.printf "True"
    else Printf.printf "False"
in List.iter iterate_by_two my_list;;
```

`List.iter` only accepts a function with one argument that is the element. Is there another function that I should look into?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `List.iter2`, which iterates over two lists in parallel, with your list and its own tail.

It throws an exception if the lists have different lengths, which is going to be the case here since the tail is obviously one element shorter, but exceptions in OCaml are cheap to catch so it's not a problem.

```
try
  List.iter2 iterate_by_two my_list (List.tl my_list)
with Invalid_argument _ -> ()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not hell-bent on using fold or iter, it's probably easiest to just write what you mean :

```
let rec iter_pairs f lst = 
  match lst with 
      [] | [_] -> ()
    | x::y::tl -> (f x y;
                   iter_pairs f (y::tl))
```

Answer (score 1):

No, but it’s easy to write one:

```
let fold_left1 f lst = List.fold_left f (List.hd lst) (List.tl lst);;

let iter_pairs f lst =
  let folder left right =
    let () = f left right in
    right
  in
  ignore (fold_left1 folder lst);;
```

Now, you can write `iter_pairs iterate_by_two my_list`.